# In Node modules, how to export a module in parts so that they can be imported in pieces as needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, node-modules

This is one of those fairly simple questions that's difficult to express to Google: I have a Node module that I want to export in pieces such that it can be imported in pieces depending on how much of it the user wants, which has a major impact on the file size.

My little module is called [Piano-Notes](https://github.com/wilson428/Piano-Notes), which exports an 88-length array of simple objects describing each key on the piano.

On top of that, I've downloaded [high-quality, public-domain samples from a Steinway](http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/MISpiano.html), courtesy of the University of Iowa Electronic Music Studios, each of which is a ~10MB `.aiff` file. (These are not included in the repo but can be downloaded with a shell script -- see the [README](https://github.com/wilson428/Piano-Notes/blob/main/README.md). I then perform the following transformations (also available as shell and Node scripts in the repo):

- Using `ffmpeg`, I reduce each sample to an `mp3` of 500ms, 1000ms and 2000ms (while also eliminating a small initial silence in the originals), which is useful since different applications will need different durations. The samples for each note are now 9KB, 17KB and 33KB, respectively.
- Using Node, I load the samples into a Buffer, convert them to base64, and bundle them into [one composite JSON file for each duration](https://github.com/wilson428/Piano-Notes/tree/main/data/audio). These files are 1MB for 500ms, 2MB for 1000ms, and 3.9MB for 2000ms. This eliminates the need for the user to download a bunch of mp3s and figure out how to get the module to locate them.
- *Here's where I run into trouble*: The user should be able to choose how many of the three samples she wants, import only those, and load them into the array of notes such that each has a `.play` method. That latter part works fine in the [Notes object's](https://github.com/wilson428/Piano-Notes/blob/main/lib/Notes.js) `.loadAudio` method.

The trouble is that my tests are all pulling in all three samples, generating 7MB files. I thought this would work (in [./lib/Audio.js](https://github.com/wilson428/Piano-Notes/blob/main/lib/Audio.js)):

```
const AUDIO = {
    500: require("../data/audio/audio_500.json"),
    1000: require("../data/audio/audio_1000.json"),
    2000: require("../data/audio/audio_2000.json")
}

const Piano_500 = { duration: 500, notes: AUDIO[500] };
const Piano_1000 = { duration: 1000, notes: AUDIO[1000] };
const Piano_2000 = { duration: 2000, notes: AUDIO[2000] };

export { Piano_500, Piano_1000, Piano_2000 }
```

However, I have [two tests](https://github.com/wilson428/Piano-Notes/tree/main/test), one of which imports all three and one of which imports just the 500ms sample:

#### test_all.js

```
import { Notes } from '../lib/Notes';
import { Piano_500, Piano_1000, Piano_2000 } from '../lib/Audio';

/* load samples into a `Notes` instance and export
export default notes;
```

#### test_500ms.js

```
import { Notes } from '../lib/Notes';
import { Piano_500 } from '../lib/Audio';

/* likewise */ 
export default notes;
```

Both of these tests produce a 7MB file. Ideally, the second would be about 1MB since it would only load the JSON file for the 500ms samples.

Clearly I don't fully grasp how `imports` and `exports` works. (I don't think I'm the only one.) My guess is that this is because the `./lib/Audio.js` file above requires all three, **even though it exports them separately**. How does one properly write export middleware like `Audio.js` such that one file can load all the pieces of a module, divide them up as necessary, and `export` those pieces for an as-needed `import`?

(I'm open to the argument that this is a dumb way to handle the whole project, and that the mp3s should all be loaded as-needed, but it's still something I ought to understand!)

Comment: What does this mean: *"Both of these tests produce a 7MB file."*?  What file?  What exactly are you measuring?

Comment: The files in test/builds are the product of running `npm run test`, and one should be much smaller than the other

Answer (score 1):

In plain node.js a module is entirely imported at once, regardless of how many individual entry points there are in the exports.  The only way to break it up so that smaller pieces can be loaded independently is to break it up into separate modules so the client of the API can then load just the modules they want to load.

But, to succeed in keeping module loads smaller, you have to make sure that your own modules aren't each pulling in lots of other stuff or most of your own other stuff.  To achieve a result where the client can successfully load only the things they actually want and for that to be an efficient and small load, then it takes very careful internal module design on your part.  This is one place where code sharing (having lots of your different pieces of code all sharing things) tends to very significantly complicate achieve small, partial loads because it's very easy for the consumer of your API to load just one module, but for it to do its work internally, it ends up pulling in lots of your other modules that you share internally.  It can be done, but it takes very careful design and the ability to measure exactly what you are achieving in loaded size for each client import.

Comment: Interesting. You refer to "plain Node.js." My tests are actually using and external Webpack build with a vanilla config, so there's ideally some tree-shaking going on, but I'm never fully understood (or even mostly understood) how that works. Is that relevant?

Comment: @ChrisWilson - Yes, I used the term "plain nodejs" explicitly because bundlers can try to isolate portions of code in the world they construct, but you didn't make any of that part of your question so I avoided discussing it.  But, if this is an API, it would have to be the users of your API that do the right bundling to tree-shake out only the pieces they need.  That's not something you can do for them because only their environment specifies what they are and aren't using.

Comment: Understood -- in any event, I want to understand this in plain Node.js. I broke the Audio middleware into three files and it functions properly. Seems like there ought to be a better solution, but I think this is the best way at the moment?

Comment: @ChrisWilson - That is correct.  Without a tree-shaking capable bundler for the end-app, the only way to make sub-portions of your code loadable is to break it up into separate module files with exports separate among them and make sure your module files can operate stand-alone without pulling your other code.